# How to correctly refer to resources?

Tags: java, jar, resources

My project contains audio resources that are in the path `src/res/sounds` under the project root. When I've been working on it in Eclipse, running would work because the project root would be the working directory.

However I exported the project into a runnable JAR file and tried to run it `java -jar` from the command line. I got `The system cannot file the file specified` errors since the working directory was now the one where I was running the command line from, and the relative path of the resources was no longer valid.

What is the correct way to work with external resources in my code (which will be later packaged in the JAR)? And how can I fix my current issue?

Comment: You may want to check all your cases, too. In Eclipse, it's not case-sensitive, but when you export it, it is. Happened to me a few times

Comment: Please show some code. Are you using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm actually sending the path to the constructor of the `Sample` class of the `beads` audio API.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the resources are in your jar file (you should unzip it and verify they are there):

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final InputStream is = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/sounds/mySound.wav");
        // do something with the inputstream
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume that the `src` dir becomes the root of the classpath. So `/res/sounds...`.